# How to invoke a global function without with short name?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have two functions organized in two files. E.g.

file a.py

```
import b

def a():
    print "a"

if __name__ == "__main__":
    b.b()
```

file b.py

```
import a           # this is what I want to eliminate

def b():
    a.a()          # could I invoke a from a.py with simply a()?
```

Is it possible to invoke `a` from b.py directly without importing `a` and just with a simple name `a()` instead of the fully qualified one?

Thanks and Best Regards!

Comment: Err - please explain why you think you want to do this?

Comment: @JonClements I don't know whether it's a good reason but I don't want other files refer `main` file directly (in this case `a.py`). Since someday I may change its name.

Comment: http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/

Comment: Why does `a.py` have to be the `main` file? Why can't you just split it in two—the part that `b` (and possibly `main`) needs is `a`; the actual top-level module or script code that `b` doesn't need is `main`. Then there's no longer a problem with `b` doing an `import a`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.  How would Python know where `a` is supposed to be?  You might have thousands of Python files on your system and mean any of them.

As you say, you have your code *organized* in two files.  Having every function in every file on your entire system be available at all times wouldn't be very organized.

But you can do this:

```
# b.py
from a import a

def b():
    a()
```

This plucks a single function from your module, so you don't need to use the module name to call it.

Comment: Thanks! But then `a.py` is tightly coupled with `b.py`. What if some day I change `a.py` to `c.py`? I should also modify `b.py`.

Comment: that's true.  you might also rename the function `a` to `foo`, or you might change `a` to do something `b.py` doesn't want, or you might decide to rewrite all your code in Erlang, or you might give up on programming and become a bartender at a tropical resort.  such is the cost of writing code  :)  best we can do is try to get it right the first time, and make our code flexible enough to fix when we got it wrong.

Comment: @Summer_More_More_Tea I'm not really sure how `from a import a` is more tightly coupled than `import a; a.a()`. Both reference exactly the same function.

Comment: @BrianMarshall: The former inserts `a` directly into your namespace. That means if you name something else `a`, or `from c import a`, or anything else, you can no longer access it. It also means anyone who imports your module sees it as `b.a`. And reflection on your module finds it as a top-level member. And so on. What you're asking is really just "Do namespaces have any point?" and I think most people agree that they do.

Comment: @abarnert I wasn't asking if namespaces have any point, no. I'm saying that whether you name it `a.a` or just `a`, you're calling the same function, and hence you aren't any more coupled with module `a`. Perhaps less, since you can't use any other variables from it without explicitly importing them, which is one of the benefits of `from import`s (self-documentation).

Answer (score 4):

Are these two files in a module? If so, you could use the `__init__.py` to import your function from `a`:

`mymodule`/`__init__.py`:

```
    from a import afunc
```

`mymodule`/`a.py`:

```
    def afunc(): 
        print "afunc"
```

And then in `mymodule`/`b.py`:

```
    from mymodule import afunc
    afunc()
```

That way, in the future if you change the name of `a.py`, you just need to change it in your `__init__.py`.

Comment: careful; this code is one step away from a circular import.  if you ever decide you want code from `mymodule.b` to be accessible at module-level, then `__init__.py` will try to import `b.py` and `b.py` will try to import `__init__.py`!

Answer (score 1):

You need to import - but you can do `from a import a`. Then you can use it as `a()`.

Comment: Thanks! But then `a.py` is tightly coupled with `b.py`. What if some day I change `a.py` to `c.py`? I should also modify `b.py`.

Comment: That is definitely a pill you'll have to swallow. What might be helpful here is organizing your code in a package. Then, import `a()` in the `__init__.py`-file, and then do `from mypackage import a`. If you use this in many scripts and you decide to change `a.py` to `c.py`, you just have to change it in one file, i.e., `__init__.py`

Answer (score 1):

If you *really* want to do this (and you *really* don't), you can always inject `a` into `b` from outside.

a.py:

```
import b

def a():
    print "a"

b.a = a

if __name__ == "__main__":
    b.b()
```

b.py:

```
"""NOTE: Before you can use this module, you must set `b.a` to a function of
   no arguments that does ____!"""

def b():
    a()
```

---

It would probably be cleaner to have a `set_a` function instead:

a.py:

```
import b

def a():
    print "a"

b.set_a(a)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    b.b()
```

b.py:

```
a = None

def set_a(func):
    a = func

def b():
    if not a:
        raise Exception('You must call b.set_a before you can call b.b!')
    a()
```

This version of the pattern actually *does* arise sometimes. Sometimes, users of `b` don't need to think about the `b.B` object, so there are convenience functions that use a singleton object—like in [`random`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/random.html). Now, if `B` has any functions that need to take a function (e.g., a handler, a callback, a substitute socket factory, …), you will probably have a `b.set_a` type function.

---

Anyway, as I explained in a comment, I think the right answer is to refactor `a.py` into a module `a.py` and a separate script `main.py` that calls it. Then `b.py` can depend on `a` without depending on your main, which is what you were trying to avoid.

a.py:

```
def a():
    print "a"
```

b.py:

```
import a

def b():
    a.a()
```

main.py:

```
import b
if __name__ == '__main__':
    b.b()
```

Nice and simple. And really, you don't even need the `if __name__` bit in this case, because nobody will ever `import main`.